# Space-Travel friendly weapons

Tags: technology, warfare, weapons, space-warfare, empire-building

When creating a background antagonist, there is a civilization of aliens who are trying to expand their space empire. They are not the typical "evil empire", but rather just an empire trying to survive and find fossil fuels, metals, and other resources. At first, they would just send satellites and stations to harvest asteroids, moons, and planets, but then they eventually will now need weapons and strong colonies to fight off locals. The empire does not use laser rifles and such, but rather guns that shoot actual bullets. In terms of maintenance and durability through travel, what kinds of firearms would be able to go through and be useful in different, alien environments? For specifics, the firearm type are shotguns and/or handheld guns that are powerful, or guns that are effective and do not use too many pieces.

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to brainstorm, and generate ideas for what weapons your bad guys have. If you really want to ask about what types of weapons require minimal maintenance and repair, you should probably [edit] your post to more clearly ask about that specifically. Keep in mind that questions that are intended to garner a large number of answers are not a good fit for this site and likely to be closed.

Comment: First of all, I think the idea of a fossil fuel hungry spacefaring civilisation is bonkers brilliant! I'm imagining a cramped and noisy diesel driven space cruiser! Add cannons and muzzle loading muskets and fancy uniforms and all that --- sounds fantastically wonderful! I think if you turned this query around and focused on one type of weapon and one particular theatre of operation you might get a more positive response!

Comment: If you're going to edit your post to only ask about firearms you may want to do more than delete one use of the word cannon, but actually [edit] your whole post to **clearly** ask one and only one question. Are you asking about muzzleloaders? Are you asking about bolt action weapons? Are you asking about semi-automatic, or fully automatic weapons? As elemtilas mentions you may also want to restrict your question to a specific theatre of operations as well. What makes sense for the gas platforms in the clouds of Titania, may not work as well for a belter asteroid mine.

Comment: "Guns that are effective and do not use too many pieces" isn't a type of firearm, that's the criteria that your firearm needs to meet? Are you asking "Is a handgun, rifle, or a shotgun better for my space dudes?" because if that's the case it's not clear in the question. In the future you should try to use the sandbox to workshop questions before asking them on the main site.

Comment: @elemtilas well it's bonkers, can't argue with that  basically steampunk in space  think it's already been done though hasn't it? a role playing game springs to mind, Victorians with space ships colonising mars wasn't it?

Comment: @Pelinore -- Everything's already been done! That shouldn't stop anyone!

Comment: A crossbow and aluminum arrows.

Comment: @elemtilas but if course, naturally  the biggest point of being aware of other examples is so you can try to make it less obvious it's essentially the same idea in your own iterations 

Comment: @sphennings I believe you are reading the question wrong.  He is not asking for a list of firearms to use, but how to optimize such firearms to be able to work properly in a variety of planetary environments.

Answer (score 2):

### No planet will have a self-combustible atmosphere

What I mean by this is that any planet with an atmosphere capable of of being caught on fire using only ambient pressure, chemicals, and a heat source will have already burned up eons before your colonists arrived.  If a planet could develop a self-combustible atmosphere (like some mixture rich in methane and oxygen) then one of two cases would be true.  The densities of these molecules will be in the wrong ratio for a sustained reaction or the first time your planet experiences a thunderstorm or meteor impact (which are both daily occurrences on most planets), the resulting concentration of heat will set the atmosphere on fire turning enough of the methane into water and CO2 that the atmosphere is no longer able to maintain a reaction.

What this means is that no matter what planet you land on, past events will dictate that no combustion caused by a traditional firearm will be able to ignite the atmosphere; so, from a safety perspective: traditional firearms will never create a significantly unpredictable reaction.

### Only Use Self-Oxidizing Explosives

Gunpowder, and most high explosives contain their own oxidizing ingredients meaning they can explode in any environment as long as they are encased to prevent environmental contaminates from messing them up.

Your standard bullet has an air-tight brass cartage which is resistant to corrosion making it already ideal for a wide range of environments.  Also, the ignition temperature of gun powder is about 500°F (260°C) which is incidentally about the same ignition temperature as crude oil.  So if your aliens are in pursuit of fossil fuels, then they will not be on very many planets with temperatures high enough to detonate their bullets.

The big things you want to stay away from are incendiary and thermobaric weapons since their effects would be much less predictable in alien atmospheres where oxygen content is unknown.

### Gyrojets, missiles, and suicide drones will be ideal for maximum versatility and predictability.

Traditional bullets will struggle to maintain velocities in thicker atmospheres or aquatic environments because they input all of their energy at launch, they leave the muzzle at a high velocity which maximizes drag causing it to slow down quickly.  A self propelled weapon leaves the muzzle at a lower velocity meaning it experiences less drag over distance; so, by accelerating over the entire trajectory, it can achieve a better kill range.

### Weapons will be made from copper or nickel alloys, not steel.

Certain atmospheres will risk rapidly corroding traditional steels, but many copper/nickel alloys are much more corrosion resistant while also being able to take the explosive pressures needed to make a firearm.

Comment: Upvoted, but please stop shooting the seafood - your second-last paragraph on bullets leaving "mussels" threw me, not to mention the "missles" in the paragraph heading :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Helium Air Rifles**

The problem with any weapon that you have no idea what kind of environment you're firing in and you have no idea how dangerous it's going to be. Anything with gunpowder is a terrible idea given that, depending on atmospheric makeup, you risk igniting a fireball in your face or failing entirely to fire it.

So, therefore, you want a sealed rifle with as inert propellant as possible - and this lends to the idea of an air-powered rifle. Pneumatic air guns have existed since the 17th century, so it's definitely within your tech range. And, additionally, don't use Earth's atmosphere (too much oxygen - see unpredictable foreign atmospheres), instead you want something incredibly inert and non-reactive, like compressed helium gas, for instance.

Comment: OP is specifically asking about firearms. A helium air rifle is not a firearm.

Comment: @sphennings IMHO this is okay: "firearm" is frequently misused and the answer gives reasoning as to why you don't want firearms but still giving a similar capability...

Comment: @sphennings It says 'gun that fires actual bullets'. And even if that doesn't qualify, frame challlenge.

Answer (score 0):

- Posting an answer is the only way to make a comment for me, due WB javascripts being too modern, I guees

You have to understand that after this "*trying to survive and find fossil fuels. ... send satellites and stations to harvest asteroids, moons, and planets ...*", after this it absolutley irrelevant what kind of weapon they do use. You like pumpguns, they use it, like swords they use it - they use whatever you like, whatever you are more familiar with.

Any star is a blob of hydrogen, which is part of fossil fuel, any gas giant is less violent blob of hydrogen, so as carbon source (methane) and it has it(methane) more than total mass of our planet(I may be a bit off here, but not necessarily by much).

Where do they get all the oxygen to burn that fossil fuel, etc.

As firearm, I reccomend bullet types, because it possible to make self aiming bullets, which can correct trajectory a little bit, reducing shots which miss a target, and as they are tigth on budget, they should think about such things, a balance of too much microelectronics which expensive (energy wise) to make and wasted shots.

Flying drones also a good stuff to figth locals, especially if they come in numbers, like swarms of them. Use a little bit of solar, not a big fan of this tech, but recharging of drones may make sense, reduces waste, and drones are equipped with hand gun type turret with smart bullets.

If smart  bullets is too much, then smart arrows can be a winner, and you save organic fuel this way as well. (Arrow may be more effective against bulletproof west btw, not all of them, but arrow tips may make all kinds of wonders.)

At this point helium rifle does not sounds that bad, so as swords may be a thing, or some virus which converts locals into fossil fuel, really unleash yourself, there is no limits for this situation, you jumped way behind the line from the start - rocket fuel from bath sht(robins family tvseries) at this point it is perfect solution.

Use whatever firearm you know - it all good.

Do not aim for a perfect weapon for them, they will have their shareof losses, and some locals will be lucky to be able to resist, due different reasoms. 70% efficiency of harvesting planets for those guys of yours is an excellent number in their situation.